# AWS Cloudwatch logs for multiple files

Tags: amazon-web-services, logging, amazon-cloudwatchlogs

I have a Java application deployed on AWS EC2 instance which creates multiple log files named application.log, application.log.1, application.log.2 and so on with increasing logs. The number of log files are not fixed and keeps on increasing with increase in logs. In Cloudwatch Logs conf file, we can specify multiple files with their absolute names, but in this case there are many files getting created at runtime with .log.1, .log.2, .log.3 .. suffix. How can I setup CloudWatch Logs to take logs for all files as they get created.

Comment: A filename progression like this normally indicates that the log is being rotated on a regular basis. If that's the case then `application.log.1` started life as `application.log`, and the CloudWatch agent will have picked up its records. I recommend that you verify this before changing your config.

Answer (score 3):

Install aws Agent

```
#change to root user
sudo su -
#update the yum package
sudo yum update -y
#install aws logs
sudo yum install -y awslogs
```

Edit the configuration file

```
vim /etc/awslogs/awslogs.conf
```

In this file add configuration like

```
[/var/log/messages]
datetime_format = %b %d %H:%M:%S
file = /var/log/messages
buffer_duration = 5000
log_stream_name = @10.20.19.93
initial_position = start_of_file
log_group_name = /aws/syslogs/unix/messages
```

in your case you can chage the file to

```
application.log.*
```

check for the origin to write the cloud watch logs

```
vim /etc/awslogs/awscli.conf
```

check for any exception

```
less /var/log/awslogs.log
```

> For More reference
>
> https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/logs/AgentReference.html

Comment: Can we have like multiple files for config? Leaving default config as is and have separate file to auto-append?

Comment: The amount of noise surrounding CloudWatch is deafening! This was the best description of allowing multiple log files I've found. Thanks @UserszrKs